# Converting an integer to an array of digits

Tags: c#

I want to know if there is a way in C# to convert an integer to an array of digits so that I can perform (Mathematical) operations on each digit alone.

Example: I need the user to input an integer i.e `123`, `456`
then the program creates two arrays of three elements `{1,2,3}`, `{4,5,6}`.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, had any ideas? You're going to get a string, so after you've validated that it is an integer you could just go through each character (number) and convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
int i = 123;
var digits = i.ToString().Select(t=>int.Parse(t.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Comment: What if I passed -123? is there a way to handle integers less than 0?

Comment: How would you expect `-123` to be represented as an array of digits? `-` is not a digit..

Answer (score 6):

You could create such array (or `List`) avoiding string operations as follows:

```
int x = 123;
List<int> digits = new List<int>();
while(x > 0)
{
    int digit;
    x = Math.DivRem(x, 10, out digit);
    digits.Add(digit);
}
digits.Reverse();
```

Alternative without using the `List` and the `List.Reverse`:

```
int x = 456;
int[] digits = new int[1 + (int)Math.Log10(x)];
for (int i = digits.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    int digit;
    x = Math.DivRem(x, 10, out digit);
    digits[i] = digit;
}
```

And one more way using `ToString`:

```
int x = 123;
int[] digits = Array.ConvertAll(x.ToString("0").ToCharArray(), ch => ch - '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this and not convert to a string:

```csharp
var digits = new List<int>();
var integer = 123456;
while (integer > 0)
{
  digits.Add(integer % 10);
  integer /= 10;
}

digits.Reverse();
```